# React Native marginTop offsetting text position in TouchableOpacity

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, touchableopacity

So I have just started developing in React Native and run across this issue where for some reason my text doesn't "move" along with the touchable opacity when I try to set marginTop on touchable opacity. Here is what I mean:

[image]

This becomes:

[image]

The relevant code is as follows (for the second image). For the first image, the code is exactly the same except there is no marginTop. Here it is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    height: '20%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginTop: 30%
  },
  buttonText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use actual pixel number instead of percent number

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'
const {height} = Dimensions.get('window')
marginTop: 0.3 * height
```

try and you will get it right

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it works but it's not accurate which is why I didn't accept it as the answer. For some reason, 0.3 * height doesn't actually make the component go down 30% of the screen but rather more than that. Any reason why the percentage doesn't work though? Shouldn't it be doing the same thing?